# Windows keeps rebooting itself when it shows the “Windows XP Professional loading…” screen

Tags: windows-xp, boot, sp3

I don't know what has happened to my Computer and I'm a new computer user. My Computer (Windows XP SP 3) is unable to boot to the logging in screen.
It loads up to the Windows Xp Professional loading screen then it automatically reboots. I've tried to go into the safe mode but it also reboots itself. What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Insert your Windows XP install disk and select the windows repair option.

There may be something faulty with your boot partition or, possibly, you may have a faulty hard-drive which caused similar problems on one of my systems.

Good luck!

Comment: Almost exactly what I'd have put. +1 from me.